# DIsable inputTextarea element based on value of a specific checkbox element within a ui:repeat list?

Tags: jsf

How can I dynamicaly disable an `inputTextarea` based on the value of a specific checkbox from within a `ui:repeat` list?

```
<ui:repeat var="eligibilityReason"
           value="#{itemDetails.itemSelected.listEligibilityReasons}">
    <h:selectBooleanCheckbox id="eligibilityReasonOptId"
                             value="#{eligibilityReason.selected}"/>
    <h:outputText value="#{eligibilityReason.eligiReasonDescr}"/>
</ui:repeat>
    
<h:inputTextarea id="ineligiReasonOtherId"
                 value="#{itemDetails.itemSelected.ineligiReasonOther}" 
                 disabled="???" />
```

Backing bean:

```
private String eligiReason;
private String eligiReasonDescr;
private boolean selected;
```

`listEligibilityReasons` gets a `List<EligibilityReason>`. So how can I dynamically enable/disable the `inputTextarea` based only on the selected/checkbox value for `eligiReason='99'`?

Comment: Should this happen instantly? Or should it happen when some form is submitted? The approach will differ slightly depending on what you are after. If you use a form you can use the `valueChangeListener` attribute in combination with the form submission to make an update. If we are not talking about a form submission - then the best approach is to use an `f:ajax` tag under the `selectBooleanCheckbox` and use a listener in combination with an `execute` attribute to target that you want to update the `inputTextArea`. If you can specify I can show you a complete example.

Comment: Instantly. The repeat list of checkboxes has a total of 9 checkboxes, and I'd like the inputTextArea to be enabled only if the 9th checkbox is checked. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should do. The ajax event is ONLY fired for item 99 and calls a Java method to set a Boolean flag for the Text Area.  This is untested but gives you the idea of what you need to do.

```xml
<ui:repeat var="eligibilityReason" value="#{itemDetails.itemSelected.listEligibilityReasons}">
     <p:selectBooleanCheckbox id="eligibilityReasonOptId" value="#{eligibilityReason.selected}" itemLabel="#{eligibilityReason.eligiReasonDescr}">
         <p:ajax listener="#{view.reason99}" disabled="#{eligibilityReason.eligiReason eq '99'}" update="ineligiReasonOtherId" />
     </p:selectBooleanCheckbox>
</ui:repeat>

<h:inputTextarea id="ineligiReasonOtherId"
    value="#{itemDetails.itemSelected.ineligiReasonOther}" 
    disabled="#{view.textAreaDisabled}" />
```

Java:

```java
   boolean textAreaEnabled = false;

   public void reason99(AjaxBehaviorEvent event) {
        textAreaEnabled = event.getSource().getValue();
    }
```

Comment: Kind of like that. In case of PrimeFaces you probably also want to `update="ineligiReasonOtherId"` when you fire the ajax event to target what it should update and show/hide. If you use vanilla JSF you use `render` with `f:ajax`  which does basically the same thing.